# I'm trying to write a function that gets a string from a field in html and return it if the first and the last characters are equal

Tags: javascript

I'm ought to do it without loops. with "if" and "else".

The user writes a random word in the text field at the html and the function needs to check if the first and last letters are equals.

If they are equal - the function will return the string without the first and the last characters.
if the characters are not equal - the function will return the written string by the user.

```js
unction firstLastletter(){

    let k = document.getElementsByClassName('text').value;
    let other = 'changed the string';
    



if(k.slice(0) == k.slice(-1)){

    return console.log(k);

}

else {
    return console.log(other);
}

}
```

i know that i miss a lot. 
but i have no clue how to implement the code in a right way.

many thanks..

Comment: You can use it as an array and compare first and last elements like `k[0] === k[k.length-1]`

Comment: that's the thing... i am not allowed to solve it with array,push && pop.
only using the if and else and the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function firstlastletter(s) {
  var first = s.charAt(0);
  var last = s.charAt(s.length-1);
  if(first == last) return s.substring(1, s.length-1) 
  else return s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mte97hg1/19/

Comment: yes. that seems to be the more fit answer.

i have questions though.

why did you put in 'last' s.length-1 ? what does -1 do ? how does it target the last character?

note it should return the string without the first and the last letters if they are the same characters.

Comment: `s.length-1` just gets me the string length minus one so that substring gets the string without the last character. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: here is what i wrote.
i almost figured this out, but i need the function to return the string without the first and last characters if they are even.

if they are not even it should return it as is.


function firstLastLetter(){



    let k = document.getElementById('text2').value;
    let str =k.slice(0,1);
    let str2 = k.slice(-1);
    
    

if(str == str2){       
     k.replace(str,'');
     k.replace(str2,'');
     console.log(k);

}

else {
    
    return k;
    
}

}